# How to run .bat file from button onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, batch-file

I have .js file that contains a JavaScript function, and an HTML file that contains the user interface.

I want to run .bat when the user clicks a button in the HTML file.

My HTML:

```
<input type='button' value='Download updated database' id='downloaddb' style='background:#6677AA;color:#FFFFFF;' onclick="i2b2.BLAST.DownloadDB();`">
```

My .js file:

```
i2b2.BLAST.DownloadDB = function()
{
    // what can I type here?
}
```

I want the user to be able to download a database file from an ftp server. I  scheduled a Windows task to run .bat daily, but my supervisor asked me to allow the user to do this job rather than run it outside my application.

Comment: You can't run `.bat` files on the client machine. You can run them on your server via ajax or by simply posting a form.

Comment: @Pointy Can I know what is the reason? I want the user to be able to download database file from ftp server.

Comment: Browsers provide no way to launch local programs on client machines. It's an obvious security precaution.

Comment: @Pointy .bat actually call .pl file. So, in this case, can I call .pl from .js?

Comment: No, the browser will not run **any** other client-side programs. Imagine what the world would be like if that were possible.

Comment: The best you could hope for would be an IE-only solution using your own ActiveX plugin, but IE11 and Edge won't support that either.

Comment: what's the reason for clicking some button? couldn't user just click that batch file?

Comment: @kay27 I develop a web page that has some functionality one of it, enable user to download database file from ftp site.

Comment: OK, next question is why you need some batch file to download, why not to make direct ftp link?

Comment: @kay27 Good question. perl file will download database files, decompress those files, and update sql tables with some information.

Comment: You may notify user that he must open bat file after download and set location.href to file url in function